# Анимирование на Jquery и конструкция path.

Tags: jquery, анимация

Всем привет.

Недавно понадобилось сделать анимацию, решил использовать jquery для этого. В процессе поиска информации столкнулся с конструкцией path,которая использовалась для создания пути движения объекта, вот в таком коде:

```
if( $theCircle.css('opacity') == 1 )
    $theCircle.stop().animate({
       path : new $.path.arc({
       center  : [409,359],
       radius  : 257,
       start   : 65,
       end     : -110,
       dir : -1
    }), opacity: '0'
},1500);
```

[Ссылка на оригинальную статью](http://www.rudebox.org.ua/stunning-circular-motion-effect/)

Интересно разобраться с этой конструкцией, кажется что в ней много возможностей.

Comment: возможно где-то пригодиться, но я бы в подобных вопросах предпочёл бы SVG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$.path** - это плагин, но не встроенная, как вы сказали, конструкция jQuery. Поэтому, для того, чтоб разобраться с его возможностями, лучше всего посетить [страничку этого проекта](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path)